Dynamically build when conditions in pyspark dataframe
I need to dynamically build when condition in pyspark data frame.
Below is our current DB value and an example source update. Based on
the type of customer(A,B) i need to determine if a specific sections
of json or changing.
If customer type is A : I need to compare if "customer-location",
"work-location" has changed comparing to DB record. If customer type
is B : I need to compare if "alternate-location" has changed comparing
to DB record.
DB value :
[
    {
        "instance": {
            "Customer": {
                "type": "A",
                "id": 123,
                "customer-location": {
                    "Name": "John doe",
                    "Street": "123 main st",
                    "CITY": "raliegh",
                    "STATE": "Nort carolina",
                    "ZIP": "55237"
                },
                "work-location": {
                    "company": "abc company",
                    "street": "winnipeg st",
                    "CITY": "South Joannaland",
                    "STATE": "California",
                    "ZIP": "61901"
                },
                "alternate-location": {
                    "Name": "John doe",
                    "Street": "123 main st",
                    "CITY": "Colorado springs",
                    "STATE": "Colorado",
                    "ZIP": "80525"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

Source :
[
    {
        "instance": {
            "Customer": {
                "type": "A",
                "id": 123,
                "customer-location": {
                    "Name": "John doe",
                    "Street": "123 main st",
                    "CITY": "Stevenchester",
                    "STATE": "West Virginia",
                    "ZIP": "55237"
                },
                "work-location": {
                    "company": "abc company",
                    "street": "winnipeg st",
                    "CITY": "South Joannaland",
                    "STATE": "Oregon",
                    "ZIP": "61901"
                },
                "alternate-location": {
                    "Name": "John doe",
                    "Street": "123 main st",
                    "CITY": "Stevenchester",
                    "STATE": "Colorado",
                    "ZIP": "80525"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

Here is what i did so far :
dbRecord = json.loads() // load DB record
dbRecordDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(dbRecord, json_schema)

sourceRecord = json.loads() // load source record
sourceRecordDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(sourceRecord, json_schema)

//join both data frames on id
source_db_join_DataFrame = dbRecordDataFrame.join(sourceRecordDataFrame.withColumnRenamed('instance', 'sourceInstance'),
                                            (dbRecordDataFrame["instance.customer.id"] == sourceRecordDataFrame[["sourceInstance.customer.id"]])).repartition(1)
                                            
                
authoritativeDf = source_db_join_DataFrame.withColumn("isUpdateValid", 
       when
           ((col("instance.customer.customer-location") != col("instance.customer.customer-location")) 
               | (col("instance.customer.work-location") != col("instance.customer.work-location")
            )
            , "true")
      .otherwise("false"))              

This works fine.
My problem : I am trying to dynamically generate the expression inside
when. How can i build below expressions dynamically based on type?
For customer type A, i want below expression to be run inside when :
((col("instance.customer.customer-location") != col("instance.customer.customer-location")) 
               | (col("instance.customer.work-location") != col("instance.customer.work-location")
            )
        

For customer type B, i want below expression to be run inside when :
((col("instance.customer.alternate-location") != col("instance.customer.alternate-location"))

I tried concatenating string but when passed to when it does not work.
when clause needs column instance. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.
